# Write Aggregate as Sql Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I'm really fighting to understand how aggregate works, and I have a solution that maps an IEnumerable to a newer C# 7 Tuple.

I'm thinking I could understand this a little bit more if this were written as Linq Sql Syntax.

Would anyone like to take a stab at it?

---

```
IEnumerable<(string Key, string Value)> many = DataToPivot();

(string XXXX, string YYYY, string ZZZZ) agg = 
many.Aggregate((XXXX: default(string),
                YYYY: default(string),
                ZZZZ: default(string)),
                  (a, i) =>
                  {
                      switch (i.Key)
                      {
                          case "xxxx":
                              return (i.Value, a.YYYY, a.ZZZZ);
                          case "yyyy":
                              return (a.XXXX, i.Value, a.ZZZZ);
                          case "zzzz":
                              return (a.XXXX, a.YYYY, i.Value);
                          default:
                              return a;
                      }
                  });
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs for those sample inputs.

Comment: This is a so-called XY problem. You're asking about Aggregate (Y) but the actual problem is: how to pivot data (X)? Aggregate is not the right method for this. Worse, LINQ doesn't support pivoting whatsoever. Neither is there a standard SQL method for pivoting and I don't think that showing the specific SQL-Server PIVOT statement would make it any more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know `Aggregate` doesn't have a query syntax (for more info see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2)). The documentation should also be able to explain how the function works.

The overload you're using is taking the initial value of the aggregate (1st argument), and applying the accumulation function (2nd argument) to each element, returning the intermediate aggregate value. So your example produces 3 strings from the input data basically returning the last string value for each key (or `default(string)` when input data doesn't contain any items for that key).

If this is your requirement you don't (and shouldn't) need to use the Aggregate function, because you are not aggregating. You can get identical results with the following example (assuming all keys are present in the `many` input):

```
IEnumerable<(string Key, string Value)> many = DataToPivot();

var d = many.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Last().Value);

(string XXXX, string YYYY, string ZZZZ) agg = (d["xxxx"], d["yyyy"], d["zzzz"]);
```

If the tuple is not required the following handles also cases where a key is not present in the data set at all (the defaults will be returned if the key doesn't exist):

```
d.TryGetValue("xxxx", out string x);
d.TryGetValue("yyyy", out string y);
d.TryGetValue("zzzz", out string z);
```

`Aggregate` would be used e.g. for string concatenation - but there you would go with `String.Join()` instead:

```
many.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Join(",", g));
```

If you would still want to use `Aggrergate` you can rewrite it like this:

```
many.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Aggregate((a, i) => i));
```

This is basically `Last()` implemented using `Aggregate()`; and with `TryGetValue` you can get what you need.

On a bit more general note: using this approach you can accommodate multiple key values without needing to specifically code them. In that case you might not even need the `ToDictionary` call, e.g. like this:

```
many.GroupBy(i => i.Key)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, Result = g.Aggregate((a, i) => i) })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: wow Marty, you nailed this one! apparently I didn't need to write that in Sql syntax at all.  that .Last() was exactly what I was looking for. 

 No wonder I was having such a problem understanding .Aggregate with this one, I had always known of .Aggregate to do things like Sum() and Count().  You saw right through this "cheat".  Extra points for explaning & showing better ways to solve this :) :)

Comment: @KevinDeus glad I could help ;)